# Matlab imcrop returns an image size zero

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to take a sample of an image using imcrop, but I am having issues.

```
patchsize = 35
[sample_width, sample_height] = size(sample);
max_width = sample_width-patchsize;
max_height = sample_height-patchsize;
x = randi([0, max_width]);
y = randi([0, max_height]);
patch = imcrop(sample,[x y patchsize-1 patchsize-1]);
```

The next part of my code is an attempt to access the pixels in patch, but I get an error : Attempted to access patch(1,1); index out of bounds because size(patch)=[0,0]

so I added,

```
disp(size(patch))
```

apparently size of patch is 0 0, but I don't understand why this is the case.  Based on answers to other questions about imcrop on stack overflow, I also tried

```
patch = imcrop(sample, [x y x+patchsize-1 y+patchsize-1])
```

This also resulted in patch having size zero

note: The size did not always return zero, in the first case, depending on what the random ints x and y were, patch would sometimes have size patchsize, but it did not happen %100 of the time, and in the second example, it would sometimes have sizes that were all over the board, but I cannot understand where this inconsistency is coming from.

Update: The problem was coming from the part of my code:

```
[sample_width, sample_height] = size(sample);
```

should have been:

```
sample_width, sample_height, depth] = size(sample);
```

Comment: It might not be the cause of error, but since size(...) gives the number of rows as first output, shouldn't you switch sample_width and sample_height in the second line of your code?

Comment: Thank you, you are definitely right, unfortunately in this case it is a square image, so not the source of the error

Comment: oh shoot. what's the size of sample just out of curiosity?

Comment: CHeck my answer I think you simply need to use another name than patch for your cropped image

Comment: 192X192, so max_width/height would be 157

Comment: If you want you can post an answer and accept it so people will see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original code is in:

```
[sample_width, sample_height] = size(sample);
```

Should be:

```
[sample_height, sample_width, sample_depth] = size(sample);
```

RGB images have 3 dimensions and declaring as above will give sample_height a larger value accounting for the width and the depth